# Choose all correct answers

Tags: probability

Suppose that you are designing a quiz that will have 20 questions on it. You want 60% (i.e., 12 correct out of the 20) to be a passing grade. What is the probability that a student who simply guesses randomly will be able to pass the test (with a 60% or better) if you make each question be of the following type?

Multiple choice, where there are two statements (a) and (b) and the student needs to select all and only the true statements. That is, the possibilities are that neither of the statements is true, only statement (a) is true, only statement (b) is true, and both statements (a) and (b) are true.

Answer (score 0):

If the student randomly guesses, he has a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$ to get each question right. Thus the number of questions he gets right follows a Binomial(20,1/4) distribution. The probability he passes is $P(Binomial(20,1/4) \geq 0.6*12)$.